# how to merge collapsible feature in bounded force directed graph?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

There are lots of example of force-directed graph and collapsible tree graph but i coundn't find collapsible feature in force-directed graph. actually i want to implement collapsible feature inside bounded force directed graph. both have different json data file so that is very confusing. in my case i have to draw topology graph which have collapsible feature and need to implement bounded force directed graph only.

my json data file structure

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "switch1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "port-1"
            },
            {
                "name": "port-2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "switch1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "switch1"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 5
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

}

here, switches can have multiple connection with other switches so that could be represent in a force-directed graph. but switch may contain ports which I want to make collapsible if ports are there under particular switch.

Comment: A collapsible force layout like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes like that. but i need to implement that feature in bounded force layout http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

Comment: Well, looks like you've got all the pieces and just need to put them together.

Comment: yes.. tried a lot but not able to integrate. most confusing part is json data file.. can u help me plz.??

Comment: please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/jaydipsinh/LSHJz/2/   problem: could not get child node under the parent node.  don't know much d3.js. plz help me out

Comment: Try starting with one of the examples and working from that.

Comment: sure, that's what i'm doing ri8 nw. but i think my json structure is not correct to fit collapsible feature.. mine json is totally different from json given in collapsible graph example

Comment: Then you should first try to get one of the examples working without modifications with your JSON.

Comment: sure, yes bounded force layout example is working without modification in my json. checkout here
http://jsfiddle.net/jaydipsinh/5x4mp/
now what next i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

OK Based on your fiddles here is a working fiddle using the example code from 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/AA7LZ/

The changes to your JSON are as follows:

JSON

```
var json = {
     "nodes": {
         name: 'RootNode',
         children: [{
             "switch_id": 1,
                 "name": "switch1",
                 "children": [{
                 "name": "port-1"
             }, {
                 "name": "port-2"
             }]
         }, {
             "switch_id": 2,
                 "name": "switch2"
         }, {
             "switch_id": 3,
                 "name": "switch3"
         }]
     },
         "links": [{
         "source": 1,
             "target": 2,
             "value": 5
     }]
 };
```

You can see that the `id` field has been changed to `switch_id` as otherwise it was colliding with the example code (you could alternatively change the references to `id` in the example code to something else if you have no control over your JSON) and I have added a `RootNode` for this to work properly.  Since you have no `size` attributes in your JSON the nodes will all look the same size.

Also I have referenced the JSON directly for the `root` rather than used D3's JSON function as demonstrated below:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 /*d3.json("readme.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});*/

 // Now get at the nodes you want displayed
 root = json.nodes;
 update();
```

Comment: such a genius man..!!  thank you so much :))  made my day happy@ have a great day !

Comment: hii.. there is one bug in code, links are not working correctly.because it connect via source and target which depends on index (0,1,2,..) but in our case we put all switches inside children so link's logic could not consider switches under children.

Comment: OK - sorry it isn't working out.  Perhaps if you can give some more example code of your JSON we can try and help more.

Comment: actually i'm drawing network topology. so first aim to display all switches as a circles and connection b/w each other represent as links so i go for bounded force layout where json structure is nodes and links but there will be multiple hosts under one switch so that should represent as collapsible so for that i guess we have to use collapsible graph's json structure. so we have to create custom JSON for both of this. hope you understand my point

Comment: Would you mind give me some instructions of how to save the modified version of json data? We are trying to update the server side after a user update. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TonyD This is too broad a question to be honest.  *One* way of doing this is to just update the individual nodes via AJAX each time part of them is changed e.g. `children, parent, name etc`